# Django 1.8 admin navigation color

Tags: django, django-1.8

Using django 1.8 how do I change the blue navigation bar on the admin interface. I don't want to change anything else, just change the nav bar color.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well, you will have to do a little bit of work.

#### OPTION 1

Create an `admin` folder in your `static` folder in your app. Inside that `static` folder, create a `css` and an `img` folders.

In your `site-packages/contrib/admin/static/css` folder, copy the `base.css` file. You can modify any and all the attributes you want in here.

You will also need to copy the img files you want to modify from `site-packages/django/admin/static/img` - see the css snippet below

Line 498:

```
.module h2, .module caption, .inline-group h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px 5px 3px 5px;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #7CA0C7 url(../img/default-bg.gif) top left repeat-x;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Line 784:

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    background: #417690;
    color: #ffc;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

seem to hold the values you want to modify. You have to copy the entire file and change the values you want changed. This file will replace the one you have when you run:

```
./manage.py collectstatic
```

This will collect all the static files from every app folder and place them in the top level static folder.

#### OPTION 2

You can copy the `base.html` template from the `django/contrib/admin/templates` folder to `yourapp/templates/admin` folder and keep the same name. At the top of the file, you can add your own css file to load after:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% block stylesheet %}{% static "admin/css/base.css" %}{% endblock %}" />
```

It will load this template instead of the base.html in the site package and you will have a similar effect.

Comment: since its in static won't I have to copy it to the server when I go into production? If so is there another way to do it where it don't have to manually copy files to the static directories?

Comment: forgot to mention that you need to run the `collectstatic` management command... ammending

Comment: [NOT RECOMMENDED] You could edit the files directly in the django site package, but as soon as you upgrade, changes will be gone... This goes against the whole point of installing third party apps and overriding their settings, templates et al.

Comment: added a second option for you